# Error when I use variables in Fortran module

Tags: loops, module, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am encountering a very very strange error when I use variables in Fortran module. It's a quite simple code. Each column of F is calculated by each column of X. X and F are all variables in module. Below is the code.

In global.f90: declaration of the module including X and F.

```
module global
implicit none
!  Parameters
real(8),parameter :: GravConst = 6.674184D-11
real(8),parameter :: PI = 3.141592653589793D0
integer :: N
real(8) :: X(3,2)
real(8) :: F(3,2)
real(8) :: omega
real(8) :: density
end module
```

In main.f90: calculation of F.

```
program main
use global
implicit none

integer I,J,K
N = 2
F = 0.0D0
X = 0.0D0
omega = 1.0
density = 0.0

!  read positions
open (1,FILE="pos.txt")
do I = 1,N
    read(1,*) (X(K,I),K=1,3)
end do

write(*,*) 'X:',(X(J,2),J=1,3)
write(*,*) 'F:',(F(J,2),J=1,3)
write(*,*) 'F(1,2):',omega*omega*X(1,2)- 4.0D0/3.0D0*PI*GravConst*density*X(1,2)
write(*,*) 'F(2,2):',omega*omega*X(2,2)- 4.0D0/3.0D0*PI*GravConst*density*X(2,2)
do I = 1,N
    !yorp force
    do K = 1,2
        F(K,I) = F(K,I) + omega*omega*X(K,I)
    end do  
    !gravity      
    do K = 1,3
        F(K,I) = F(K,I) - 4.0D0/3.0D0*PI*GravConst*density*X(K,I)
    end do
end do
write(*,*) (F(J,2),J=1,3)
end
```

The values of F(1,2) and F(2,2) calculated directly are printed before the loop. After the loop, the final values of F(:,2) are printed. Here is the result using intel/18.0.2. It's obvious that the result calculated by loop is wrong.

```
X: -4.97716000000000       0.897938000000000       -11.4228000000000
F: 0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000
F(1,2): -4.97716000000000
F(2,2): 0.897938000000000
-4.69400000000000       -4.97716000000000    0.000000000000000E+000
```

It seem like something strange happening in the loop... But if I change the order of the calculation in the loop, the result would be correct.

```
do I = 1,N 
    !gravity      
    do K = 1,3
        F(K,I) = F(K,I) - 4.0D0/3.0D0*PI*GravConst*density*X(K,I)
    end do
    !yorp force
    do K = 1,2
        F(K,I) = F(K,I) + omega*omega*X(K,I)
    end do 
end do

X: -4.97716000000000       0.897938000000000       -11.4228000000000
F: 0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000
F(1,2): -4.97716000000000
F(2,2): 0.897938000000000
-4.97716000000000       0.897938000000000    0.000000000000000E+000
```

If I use local variables rather variables in module, the result would also be correct.

Below are pos.txt and makefile I used.

```
2.64530000  -7.20517000     -4.69400000 
-4.97716000     0.89793800  -11.42280000

# Start of the makefile
COMPILER=ifort -O2
DEMBody: global.o main.o
    $(COMPILER)  -o DEMBody global.o main.o
global.mod: global.o global.f90
    $(COMPILER)  -c global.f90
global.o: global.f90
    $(COMPILER)  -c global.f90
main.o: global.mod main.f90
    $(COMPILER)  -c main.f90
clean:
    rm global.mod global.o main.o
# End of the makefile
```

Or, you could try this input. It would be more clear.

```
X(1,1) = 1.0
X(2,1) = 2.0
X(3,1) = 3.0
X(1,2) = 4.0
X(2,2) = 5.0
X(3,2) = 6.0
```

You would get a confusing result for 'F':

```
F(:,1): 1.000        2.000       0.000E+000
F(:,2): 3.000        4.000       0.000E+000
```

The correct result should be

```
F(:,1): 1.000        2.000       0.000E+000
F(:,2): 4.000        5.000       0.000E+000
```

It seems that the element of X/F has been moved by one cell.

Comment: Because "density" is zero, the second part of the loop, the gravity, is actually useless. But if we delete this part, the result would be correct.

Comment: I tried intel/15.0.6 and intel/17.0.7, and the result are both correct. Maybe it has something to do with the compiler?

Comment: I tried -O1 rather than -O2, and the result is correct.

Comment: Please provide the file pos.txt

Comment: using the position you provide for particle 2 in pos.txt, I cannot reproduce the bug.

Comment: make sure that you have recompiled all files for every test. makefiles are very convenient for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I have uploaded the files needed in the end of the question.

Comment: Looks like a problem with floating point/optimization.  Try with `-O0` or `-fp-model strict`.

Comment: Thanks! They both solved the problem. Could you give me more information about this problem? I really wanna know why.

Comment: Compiling with ifort version 17.0.4 gives me the correct result, but with version 18.0.3 I get the same erroneous result as you. I think you should ask this in the intel forums, maybe it's a bug in the compiler! I can't think of any reason why it behaves this way.

Comment: Doing a lot of unrelated stuff also seems to solve the problem. For instance, changing the loop `do I = 1,N` to `do I = 1,2` fixes it. Also, putting any write command inside the loop fixes it as well. It doesn't even have to write to stdout, you can write to a variable (`write(str_buff, *) 'hello'` works as well). If you remove variable `N` from the module and define it in your main program file it also fixes it! I'm pretty convinced it's a bug, you should report it!